# Kerberos oracle authentication error ERROR: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, active-directory, kerberos

I am facing error
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor

when I try to connect with sqlplus /@XE

I am doing oracle kerberos authentication setup I did all the steps but not sure where I am getting wrong